# How to use Slider instead of Scrollviewer Vertical Bar in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am using the Slider control instead of using Scrollviewer Vertical Bar.
But it is not working properly.

```
scrollViewer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, (ThumbnailSizeHeight + PADDING) * [list count]);
slider.maximumValue =  (ThumbnailSizeHeight + PADDING) * [list count];
```

Please correct me.

Comment: It's not so simple to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Until the `contentSize` is larger than the frame size of the scroll viewer, you don't need a scroll. So,

```
CGFloat scrollableHeight = (ThumbnailSizeHeight + PADDING) * [list count] - scrollViewer.frame.size.height;
if ( scrollableHeight <= 0 ) {
    slider.enabled = NO; // or use the `hidden` property
} else {
    slider.enabled = YES; // or .hidden based on what you do in `if`
    slider.maximumValue = scrollableHeight;
}
```

later on the interface action of the slider on `UIControlEventValueChanged`,

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    scrollViewer.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, slider.value);
}
```

Comment: @Sezhian Did this help? Do you need further assistance on this?